# How do I apply pseudo-selector styles from a parent with shadow DOM?

Tags: html, css, polymer, shadow-dom

I am basically trying to duplicate the behavior of the [CSS Tricks](https://css-tricks.com/) navigation bar, with the animation of the item labels flying in from the left when any part of the whole bar is hovered over. I am trying to do this using Web Components and Polymer.

I have my HTML structured (roughly) like this:

**index.html**

```
<!-- ... head stuff ... -->
<body>
  <my-app></my-app>
</body>
```

**my-app.html**

```
<dom-module id="my-app">
  <nav>
    <my-nav-item url="/"
                 text="Home"
                 icon="home.svg#nav-icon-home"></my-nav-item>
  </nav>
</dom-module>
```

**my-nav-item.html**

```
<dom-module id="my-nav-item">
  <a href$="[[url]]">
    <svg height="20px" width="20px" viewBox="0 0 20 20">
      <use href$="[[icon]]"></use>
    </svg>
    <span>[[text]]</span>
  </a>
</dom-module>
```

And the CSS looks something like this:

**my-app.html**

```
nav {
  width: 75px;
  height: calc(100% - 60px);
  background: #222d32;
}
```

**my-nav-item.html**

```
a {
  display: block;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
  margin: 25px auto;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-family: 'Exo 2', sans-serif;
  font-size: 12px;
}

svg {
  fill: white;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

span {
  display: block;
  margin: 10px auto;
  transform: translateX(-200px);
  transition: 0.1s;
}
```

The `span` starts off-screen as expected, and when I use `a:hover span` with `transform: translateX(0)` it works perfectly well with the text flying in from the left. I would, however, like ALL the labels to fly in from the left when any part of `nav` is hovered over, just like [CSS Tricks](https://css-tricks.com/)' website does.

How do I set the `nav:hover my-nav-item span` `transform` property without breaking separation of concerns?

Comment: Can you provide a codepen or something as a minimal example of the issue?

Comment: As a `span` does not even exists in your questions sample code it is hard to understand the markup structure. Please add a working code snippet within the question or else any attempt would be a guess

Comment: Guesses are great! :)

Codepen does not seem to support custom elements. Do you know of another playground/sandbox site that does support them?

Comment: Codepen works for me...https://codepen.io/anon/pen/XRpvmJ

Comment: @LGSon - That is not using `dom-module` or HTML imports as per the [Web Components](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Web_Components) specs.

Comment: No, true, and I also missed the _to do this using Web Components and Polymer_ part in your question and since that is something I don't use, all pass here and now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up fixing the problem (reluctantly) with `::shadow /deep/`:

**my-app.html**

```
nav:hover worf-nav-item::shadow /deep/ span {
  transform: translateX(0);
}
```

What *might* be nice is something along the lines of the native CSS properties used as mixins as proposed at 11:40 in the talk from Polymer Summit 2015: ["Polymer's Styling System."](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IbOaJwqLgog)

I might propose something like this:

**my-app.html**

```
nav:hover {
  --transform-no-translate-x: {
    transform: translateX(0);
  }
}
```

**my-nav-item.html**

```
span {
  @apply(--transform-no-translate-x);
}
```

#### *But wait... there's more!*

I actually kept playing with it while writing this and came up with another solution. I like this much better.

**my-app.html**

```
nav {
  --nav-transform: translateX(-200px);
}

nav:hover {
  --nav-transform: translateX(0);
}
```

**my-nav-item.html**

```
span {
  transform: var(--nav-transform);
}
```